# Not able to display database from my laravel website

Tags: php, laravel

here  is my controller named CommentController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use Auth;





class CommentsController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    return view('comments.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{


    $comment= new Comment();
    $comment->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->body=$request->body;
    $comment->save();
    return back();
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show()
{
    //

 $comments=comment::all();
 return view('comments',['comments'=>$comments]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

here is my layout code named create.blade.html

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <h1>DONE</h1>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row new-post">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <header><h3>Comments</h3></header>
            <form action="/comments" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post"            rows="5" placeholder="Your review on above game"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Comment</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

   <?php foreach($comments as $comment) ?>
   <h1><?php echo $comment ?> <h1>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my routes code named as web.php

```
<?php



Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::resource('comments','CommentsController');

Route::get('comments.create','CommentsController@show');
?>
```

Now here whatever data I am submitting is getting entered in database but when I trying to display that data it is giving me error Undefined variable: comments. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not passing `$comments` variable from `create()` method which should look like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $comments = comment::all();
    return view('comments.create', ['comments' => $comments]);
}
```

Also remove `Route::get('comments.create'`, because it's a bad idea to try to override resource routes. Use `create()` to display the form and `show()` to display one comment.

Comment: Thanks it worked.But i would like to know how did you can to know that $comments = comment::all();
    return view('comments.create', ['comments' => $comments]); this code should be added in create function or any link to tutorial from which i can understandt his would be very nice of you.

Comment: You're using `Route::resource()` which is building few standard CRUD routes to use these with resource controllers. You should learn about how [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) work.